# Visibility of records in a junction object - AND based or relationshipOrder based?

Tags: permissions, master-detail

I have a question about junction object record visibility. I will start with a snippet from an SFDC document:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm&language=en

"Sharing access to a junction object record is determined by a user's sharing access to both associated master records and the Sharing Setting option on the relationship field. See Custom Object Security Overview. For example, if the sharing setting on both parents is Read/Write, then the user must have Read/Write access to both parents in order to have Read/Write access to the junction object. If, on the other hand, the sharing setting on both masters is Read-Only, a user with Read-Only rights on the master records would have Read/Write access to the junction object."

So my questions are:

1) In order for a user to have at least read access to a record in a junction object does the user have to have read on the master records in *both* master objects? Or just the master record where the master relationshipOrder = 0?
2) When using a junction object is there any scenario where a user can have read to one master object record and no visibility to the other master object record and still have read to the junction object record? Yes, I am asking question #1 a slightly different way :-) .

Answer (score 6):

If you followed the link from the page you referenced to [Custom Object Security Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_security.htm&language=en_US) you'd have found this:

> View a record:    “Read” permission and read access to the related master
>   record. If the record has two master records in a many-to-many
>   relationship, the user must have read access to both master records.

1) Yes, the user must have at least read access to both Master records.

2) No.